How much notation should there be in a formal proof? Is there a general guideline?
I am writing a conference paper in formal language theory with an involved proof and I've found myself struggling with notation. In particular, I don't know when to favor notation and when to favor normal words. I want the proof to be as clear and precise as possible, but it often isn't obvious what leads to maximal clarity and precision.
For example, I introduce $\mathcal{C}$ as the "set of constants" and $\mathcal{V}$ as the "set of variables". Later, I could say "$x \in \mathcal{C}$", or I could say "$x$ is a constant". Similarly, I could say "$y \in \mathcal{C} \cup \mathcal{V}$", or I could say "$y$ is a constant or a variable".
Which of these is clearer or more precise? The notation is shorter but the words might be easier to parse and both are unambiguous. Are there any general guidelines for this?
Thank you much!
(Also, other papers in this area use wildly different notation so they aren't much help.)

That is a difficult question to answer. For me, however, $x\in\mathcal C$ is just as formal as $x$ is constant. What is not 'so formal' for me, for example, would be to write $f$ is smooth instead of $f\in C^\infty$, since one could also understand $f\in C^1$ or whatever.

It’s a personal choice. I err on the side of not requiring my audience to be parsers.
